# Unable to get a price from a web page by using XPaths

Tags: python, html, dom, xpath, web-crawler

I am using the Content Egg WordPress plugin, which scrapes the price and updates it, but I can't get prices from a web page. (https://www.trazy.com/experience/detail/lotte-world-seoul-discount-ticket)

I tried these XPaths.

```
`.//div[@class='price-desktop']//span[@class='selling notranslate']`
`.//div[@class='price-desktop']//span[2]`
```

But I can see that the Xpaths find the elements but it returns "0".
[Please see the development tool image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7U9P.jpg)

Please, help me to find the right XPath to get the price.

Answer (score 0):

When I inspected the outerHTML, I could see that there are multiple matching nodes with `//span[@class='selling notranslate']` so it won't return you the element that you want.

Please use

```
//div[@class='price-desktop']//span[@class='selling notranslate']
```

to locate price web element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It's the same XPath that I tried as I mentioned on the inquiry. It doesn't work.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: When you say it does not work, what is the error ?

Comment: As I am using a plugin, Content Egg, I can't see the error. I added two products to the blog post. (https://www.ivisitkorea.com/seonglagwon/) The first one works, and the second one is the product that I can't get the price with the upper XPath. It's empty.

Comment: I would need to see the code that you've tried.